# Short story with a girl gang who like to whistle the tune of "I Wish I Was an Oscar Mayer Wiener"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have the traces of a short story bouncing around in my head. I'd guess it dates from the late 60's, or maybe 70's.

A guy has been out of circulation for several years (military? prison?) and returns home to a city in a shambles.

The notable part I remember is a girl gang, who like to whistle the tune of "I Wish I Was an Oscar Mayer Wiener", then laugh in a sinister manner. The protagonist never learns exactly what it means, but it's clearly not nice.

Given my reading habits at the time, this was certainly sci-fi, and probably appeared in an anthology. It was presented as a dystopic/urban social decay situation. It also incorporated elements of social reversal, as there were no male gangs providing menace, only women. And the "Oscar Mayer" bit was certainly suggestive of sexual violence as well.

Comment: I confess the only thing that comes to mind is "..you don't fool around with no Oscar Mayer Wiener; you must be sure that your girl is pure, for the funky cold medina" - yes I know this is of absolutely no help, sorry!